# conditions for Gauss_jordan elimination with no pivoting

Tags: inverse

Please note that here is Gauss_jordan elimination which help us get inverse of A.

I am wondering, is there any condition that it could work without pivoting?

I try to prove this under column diagonally dominant, but I could pass one step in my proof.

Has anyone heard about sth about this topic?

yes, we could naively say for each step $A^{(i)}$ has no 0 elements in the diagonal line but
could we directly add some conditions on A rather than $A^{(i)}$?

thanks

Comment: This can only be done when you don't have zeros in the diagonal.

Comment: yes, but the condition is based on $A^{(i)}$ of each step not on A itself. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. But be careful because without pivoting GJ is numerically unstable.

Comment: But I feel it is not a condition directly on A, how could we tell others that in each step, there is no 0. Like LU factorization, if the A is diagonally dominant, then no pivoting needed. Is there something like this?

Comment: The stability of the algorithm is determined by the chosen norm and the residual in each step. Look at its LU decomposition. If $\| L \|_{\infty}\| U \|_{\infty}$ is a small multiple of $\| A \|_{\infty}$, then we can say that $\| \delta A \|_{\infty}/ \| A \|_{\infty}$ is a small multiple of roundoff error and you have stability.

Comment: no, I do not refer to stability, I mean the condition for gauss_jordan does not need pivoting

Comment: You would have to a priori calculate the determinant of the sub-matrices. This is, of course, pointless outside of an academic exercise. The sub-matrices are a feature of $A$. I think you're getting hung up on the fact that you can't just look at $A$ and decide if it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but could you say more about how to connect determinant with sub matrix to the non-zero diagonal element in each step?

Comment: To verify if the sub-matrices are singular. The algorithm stops if you're not allowed to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking whether a given matrix $A$ can be written as $A =L\cdot U$ where $L$ is lower triangular, $U$ is upper triangular and both are invertible. This is called the Gauss decomposition ( you may have an extra diagonal term in the middle - harmless).

The following result is true:

The matrix $A$ can be written as $A = L\cdot D \cdot U$  (all invertible) if and only if all the leading principal minors of $A$ are nonzero.